# Spring Data JPA - bidirectional relation with infinite recursion

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, infinite-recursion

First, here are my entities.

**Player** :

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.UUIDGenerator.class, 
property="id")
public class Player {

    // other fields

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "pla_fk_n_teamId")
    private Team team;

    // methods

}
```

**Team** :

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.UUIDGenerator.class, 
property="id")
public class Team {

    // other fields

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team")
    private List<Player> members;

    // methods

}
```

**As many topics already stated, you can avoid the StackOverflowExeption in your WebService in many ways with Jackson.**

That's cool and all but JPA still constructs an entity with infinite recursion to another entity before the serialization. This is just ugly ans the request takes much longer. Check this screenshot : [IntelliJ debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOHdV.png)

Is there a way to fix it ? Knowing that I want different results depending on the endpoint. Examples :

- endpoint **/teams/{id}** => Team={id..., members=[Player={id..., **team=null**}]}
- endpoint **/members/{id}** => Player={id..., team={id..., **members=null**}}

Thank you!

**EDIT : maybe the question isn't very clear giving the answers I get so I'll try to be more precise.**

I know that it is possible to prevent the infinite recursion either with Jackson (@JSONIgnore, @JsonManagedReference/@JSONBackReference etc.) or by doing some mapping into DTO. The problem I still see is this : both of the above are post-query processing. The object that Spring JPA returns will still be (for example) a Team, containing a list of players, containing a team, containing a list of players, etc. etc.

**I would like to know if there is a way to tell JPA or the repository (or anything) to not bind entities within entities over and over again?**

Comment: I see double information there. Why do you need to save the team within the player entity, if you have the membership information already in your team entity? The REST API does not need to reflect your db scheme.

Comment: "Why do you need to save the team within the player entity" Cause I want to have a complete reference of an entity. When I retrieve a player I want to give all the information about him.

Comment: @JsonManagedReference/@JsonBackReference works for me to prevent recursion on serialized GET, even with FetchType.EAGER.  I get no stack trace indicating unbound recursion.  Maybe your debugger exacerbated the problem, by asking for more than Jackson did.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is how I handle this problem in my projects.

I used the concept of data transfer objects, implemented in two version: a full object and a light object.

I define a object containing the referenced entities as List as `Dto` (data transfer object that only holds serializable values) and I define a object without the referenced entities as `Info`.

A `Info` object only hold information about the very entity itself and not about relations.

Now when I deliver a `Dto` object over a REST API, I simply put `Info` objects for the references.

Let's assume I deliever a `PlayerDto` over `GET /players/1`:

```
public class PlayerDto{
   private String playerName;
   private String playercountry;
   private TeamInfo;
}
```

Whereas the `TeamInfo` object looks like

```
public class TeamInfo {
    private String teamName;
    private String teamColor;
}
```

compared to a `TeamDto`

```
public class TeamDto{
    private String teamName;
    private String teamColor;
    private List<PlayerInfo> players;
}
```

This avoids an endless serialization and also makes a logical end for your rest resources as other wise you should be able to `GET /player/1/team/player/1/team`

Additionally, the concept clearly separates the data layer from the client layer (in this case the REST API), as you don't pass the actually entity object to the interface. For this, you convert the actual entity inside your service layer to a `Dto` or `Info`. I use http://modelmapper.org/ for this, as it's super easy (one short method call).

Also I fetch all referenced entities **lazily**. My service method which gets the entity and converts it to the `Dto` there for runs inside of a transaction scope, which is good practice anyway.

#### Lazy fetching

To tell JPA to fetch a entity lazily, simply modify your relationship annotation by defining the fetch type. The default value for this is `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` which in your situation is problematic. That is why you should change it to `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`

```
public class TeamEntity {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<PlayerEntity> members;
}
```

Likewise the `Player`

```
public class PlayerEntity {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "pla_fk_n_teamId")
    private TeamEntity team;
}
```

When calling your repository method from your service layer, it is important, that this is happening within a `@Transactional` scope, otherwise, you won't be able to get the lazily referenced entity. Which would look like this:

```
 @Transactional(readOnly = true)
public TeamDto getTeamByName(String teamName){
    TeamEntity entity= teamRepository.getTeamByName(teamName);
    return modelMapper.map(entity,TeamDto.class);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I came across DTO to resolve the problem I'm having after some research. Once again it's cool BUT the result of the query still is the same before mapping ! Isn't there a way to tell JPA (or the repository, dunno) to not bind entities over and over again ?

Comment: That's exactly what lazy fetching is for. The default fetch type is `FetchType.EAGER` . You don't want this. Simply modify you relation annotation (`@ManyToOne`) to `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`. This requires a active transaction scope to fetch the referenced entity, but will load it only if said so.

Comment: All right I did what you said (LAZY fetching and Transactional scope), just didn't do any DTO mapping yet to see the result, and I once again get a StackOverflowError. Which I don't understand because I clearly see in the debugger that my list of players contains a Team object but with all its field to null.

Comment: Oh and I even removed the @JsonIdentityInfo on both Player and Team entities. That's probably why I get the error, which means that I need the LAZY fetching, transactional scope and the JSON serialization parameterized to get what I need. Thought that the LAZY fetching would be enough to do the trick. :P

Comment: If the serialization happens within the transaction scope and you remove the `@JsonIdentityInfo` it will keep doing the recursion again ;) The `Dto` would prevent this as it has a defined depth.

Comment: Guess I can't avoid DTO, seems to be cleaner than just letting Jackson doing all the work. Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 8):

In my case I realized I did not need a bidirectional (One To Many-Many To One) relationship.

This fixed my issue:

```java
// Team Class:
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Player> members = new HashSet<Player>();

// Player Class - These three lines removed:
// @ManyToOne
// @JoinColumn(name = "pla_fk_n_teamId")
// private Team team;
```

Project ***Lombok*** might also produce this issue. Try adding `@ToString` and `@EqualsAndHashCode` if you are using Lombok.

```java
@Data
@Entity

@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = { "members"}) // This,
@ToString(exclude = { "members"}) // and this

public class Team implements Serializable {

// ...
```

This is a nice guide on infinite recursion annotations https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Comment: Oh my.  I wished I could give you a 100 up votes.  I tried everything and didn't realize it was Lombok causing the issue.  This fixed my problem.

Comment: Also, if your entities have a lot of properties like mine sometimes do, you can use:
`@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)`
`@ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)`  Then, on each member you want to include, just annotate with `@EqualsAndHashCode.Include`

Answer (score 6):

You can use [@JsonIgnoreProperties](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) annotation to avoid infinite loop, like this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties("members")
private Team team;
```

or like this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties("team")
private List<Player> members;
```

or both.

Comment: It avoids infinite loops at the serialization time, but JPA still builds an entity with an infinity of entities.

Comment: Don't have any overrides on them. What does that have to do with my problem ?

Comment: @MickaëlBénès Just fetch the references lazily. There is usually no reason to fetch a referenced entity eagerly.